# postgresql Error [42P17]: ERROR: "eMAR_201501" is not partitioned when trying to create child tables from parent table

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create partition of existing table and it is saying Partitioning is not enabled
how can I fix it. basically I want to create partition of existing table which is very huge and let me know how can I do it
also I can not enable partition using this option

[image]

this is how I am creating partition

```
CREATE TABLE public."eMAR_2012" PARTITION OF public."eMAR_201501"
   FOR VALUES FROM ('2012-01-01 12:00 AM') TO ('2019-12-31 11:59 PM');
```

Comment: What is your Postgres version? Do you want all existing rows into the same partition? Or do you need to distribute the existing rows in many different partitions? Please **[edit]** your question and add the _complete_ `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in question (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) -  [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please) and an explanation on how the partitioning strategy should look like.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
the postgres version is 12.4 and I want to move data only with date range as I mentioned in quetiion now

Comment: You should also explain what problem you are trying to solve with partitioning. You can't just attach a partition to a non-partitioned table. You will have to copy the data.

Comment: I am trying this for better performance

Comment: You will have to drop the table and create it again as a partitioned table.

Comment: you saying droping the master table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add a partition to a non-partitioned table. If the *existing* data should be re-partitioned, the only thing you can do, is to create an empty partitioned table with the partitions you want and then copy the data from the non-partitioned table to the partitioned table.

If all of the existing data can be put into a single partition, you could rename the existing table to a different name, create a new partitioned table with the "old" table name, and then attach the existing table as a partition to that newly created partitioned table. This is typically used if partitioning is implemented to quickly delete old/obsolete rows.

But again: if the *existing* data needs to be distributed between multiple partitions, the only way you can do that is to copy the data from the old non-partitioned table into a partitioned table.

Comment: thanks
I will create table as partitioned and then create its child partioned tables and will move data to them